# Open outlook in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, iis, outlook, iis-5

I have an ASP.net application that would open an outlook on a certain function.
sample code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
        oNS.Logon(null, null, true, true);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        oMail.Subject = "Sample Subject";
        oMail.To = "test@yahoo.com";
        oMail.HTMLBody = "Sample Paragraph";
        oMail.Display(false);

        oApp = null;
        oNS = null;
        oMail = null;
```

This is working just fine when I run it through Visual Studio.
After that I publish it to IIS 5.1 so basically i'm using windows xp machine.

Now I've run it using the published version on IIS, and i got the error *"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"*.

I've fixed it by putting an impersonation on the web.config file. Now the application is running successfully without error.

But the problem now is it doesn't seem to open the outlook, I've tried debugging it via attach to process on aspnet_wp.exe and was able to attach to a break point and it seemed to pass through all the lines without throwing an error but i just doesn't open the outlook.

Am I missing something to configure on the IIS level?
Thanks!

Comment: Everytime I see "MS Office" running on a Server I have to cry. Don't do that. Office is not supposed to run on Servers. Especially with Outlook you have to deal with profiles etc.. If you wanna send an email use SmtpClient and MailMessage classes.

Comment: Haha that's right, i think you've dealt with this before and you know its a pain on the head. Anyway thank you for your suggestion and actually that's what i'm trying to do right now :)

Comment: Good choice :-) SmtpClient is very easy though. There are tons of samples on google. Have fun sending emails.

Comment: Only thing here is it will send the email automatically without opening up the outlook, and for the purpose for reviewing the entry :(

Comment: err... outlook won't open on the client anyway if it's installed on the server (?)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the web app's application pool under a user that has access permissions. or even you can try to restart the iis  and try out. it basically causing because of security issues concenrend.  when i googled this issue, i got this [Aspnet Security contexts](http://www.communitycoder.com/)

suggestions may help to solve problem.

1. Enter identity credentials in webconfig or in iis
2. Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files give write permissions.

Comment: 1. i put this in webconfig
identity impersonate="true"
          userName="<myadministrator account>"
          password="<password of my account" />
2. done and 
It did not work.. and there's no application pool on IIS 5.1 it shouldn't be the case because it doesn't throw any exception regarding security